# How to deal with Hunters as a Paladin?

Tags: hearthstone

My paladin deck is having a bit of trouble against Hunter Zoo as they almost always run  [Unleash the Hounds](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Unleash_the_Hounds%E2%80%8E), which limits my hero ability's usefulness since I like to spam 1/1 minions on my side.  They are also quite adept at stripping divine shields with explosive traps and tiny minions.  What are some strategies I can use to counter hunter decks.  The only reliable board clear I have is consecrate and its not guarenteed I'll have one on hand when I need it.

Comment: have you tried using equality and wild pyromancers in your deck?
pyro+quality is one of the best clears ingame, while you can clear unleash the hounds boards with pyromancers + holy light.

also do you use argus?

Comment: @Werdli that clears my side too though, and usually by my turn after unleash the hounds the damage has been done. regarding Argus, I use sejins instead since its hard to have a good target(much less 2) on the board by turn 4 for it to buff.

Comment: what 2/3/4 drops do you use? could you maybe screenshot your deck?

Comment: @Werdli I'm at work, but I'll ss my deck once I get home. My 2 drops are argent protector, ooze, faerie dragon. 3 drops are acolyte of pain blood knight. 4 drops, too many to list. sejin, spellbreaker, truesilver, chillwind, blessing of kings, etc etc.

Comment: Post your deck here and we can help you out with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a deck built around flooding the board with minions, I've noticed Hunters tend to be by far the largest issue, because in addition to having access to easy and cheap board clear, they also have unleash the hounds, one of the most insane 2 drops in the game. I personally have two decks, paladin and shaman, that are built around having a large number of small minions on the field.

Firstly a word of advice based on your commented deck list. If your do really enjoy flooding the board using your power, I would highly recommend you consider cutting down some on your four drops and increasing your number of three drops and maybe even two drops. The advantage of this is that, it makes you more likely to be able to use all your mana in a turn for maximum efficiency. For Instance:

- Turn 2: Use Power or play relevant 2 drop, depending on board state and opponent power.
- Turn 3: Play 3 drop
- Turn 4: Use Power and play relevant 2 drop, OR play 4 drop.
- Turn 5: Use Power and play relevant 3 drop.

Alright, regarding your specific issues against hunters, one of the best counters to unleash the hounds is high toughness taunt creatures, or having a number of taunt creatures. The big issue is that most hunter decks will be running 2 silence owls, so oftentimes they'll simply silence your large taunt creature, and then attack past it. Some possibilities to fill this role include:

- Sen'jin Shieldmasta: Hands down one of the best taunt minions in the game, Sen'jin can usually eat up anywhere from 3-5 hounds from unleash the hounds, depending on how much support your opponent has for the unleash. In addition, Sen'jin is relevant against a large number of other decks unlike some other large taunt creatures. I would definitely consider running 2 of these if you tend to have issues against aggro decks. The big downside of him against hunter decks, as is the case with most bigger creatures, is he dies to a kill command.
- Tirion Fordring: A very powerful legendary creature, if you have him, I would highly recommend running him, as he's hard to kill and still impactful upon dying. The big issue with him is that he is one of the biggest blowouts if he's silenced, just becoming a measly 6/6 for 8 if he is.
- Abomination: Abomination is, in my opinion, a very underrated minion. He is amazing against Unleash the Hounds specifically, almost always clearing all the hounds on his own, in addition to any potential support your opponent might play, such as timber wolf and starving buzzard. The big downside of him for you is that he basically acts like an exploding trap, most likely killing all your token minions.
- Defender of Argus: Defender of Argus is an amazing creature, especially for a paladin, who is easily capable of making sure he has the creatures to use it with. The big downside of him in this case is that if your opponent has Timber Wolf, their hounds will just trade for your 2/2 soldiers. I would still recommend at least running one of him in your deck, if not two, because there are many times that he is relevant.
- Sunwalker: One of the hardest to straight out kill taunt creatures, sunwalker can be very impactful upon the board. The big downside of him is that he's highly susceptible to silencing, and is somewhat high costing, especially if he gets silenced.
- Fen Creeper: Generally considered to just be a worse version of Sen'jin, he is still not a bad consideration to put in to the deck if you're having that much difficulty against hunters. The benefit that Fen Creeper has over Sen'jin is that he won't die to a single kill command, taking both a kill command and a hound to kill, and still eating up between 3 and 6 hounds if they don't have kill command.
- Sunfury Protector: A tiny version of Defender of Argus, I would be hesitant to run this in your deck, since you're most likely going to have only small minions to use her with. Still, her ability can be very relevant, as she'll force your opponent to clear two of your minions before they can attack you.
- Mogu'shan Warden: As a last ditch effort, if Unleash the Hounds is absolutely the bane of your deck, I would run Mogu'shan. He is often very irrelevant against opponents, but against Unleash the Hounds specifically, he is one of the best minions out there. Again though, he's not very good against most other decks.

Worrying about clearing the board of an unleash the hounds after their turn is less of a big deal, as you should probably be saving your consecrations for just such an occasion if possible. If that is a concern though, you can also add Avenging Wrath to your deck, as it's an excellent board clear against Unleash the Hounds, and in general, is just a rather good spell, at worst being 8 damage to the opposing hero for 6 mana.

Regarding the other aspects of the hunter, having big taunt creatures also helps to avoid your creatures' divine shields from being removed, by protecting the smaller divine shielded minions. In addition, divine shielding a Sen'jin Shieldmaster or Abomination can be pretty powerful.

In respect to the explosive trap, unfortunately, there's not many counters to it in a paladin deck besides playing around it, or using divine shields. If you're truly worried about it, consider doing little other than using your power until your opponent uses their first explosive trap. If you bait out an explosive trap, you can much more confidently attempt to establish board control by playing a number of cards from your hand after it explodes. Divine shields though do suffer from the issue of being easy to trade a small minion in to remove it. It is why I would probably not run Hand of Protection, but would definitely still run Argent Protector, as a 2/2 with 'Give a friendly minion divine shield' is pretty good.

Comment: oh I have more than just the 2/3 drops I listed, those were just what I recall at the time.  I will tweak my deck a bit with your advice and play a few hands when I get home.

Comment: @z- Honestly, the things that make unleash the hounds so powerful is cards like scavenging hyena and starving buzzard played before hand in the same, which there really is no counter in paladin decks, due to the paladin's secrets being unable to kill creatures that aren't attacking. And still, if you have that many 4 drops, I would consider taking out some if possible.

Comment: here's my deck after some modifications, seems to work better.  I might still not have enough taunts: http://imgur.com/yWWp3rN

Comment: @z- Personally, I would recommend taking out 'Stampeding Kodo', 'Humility', and 'Holy Light', potentially in favor of the other cards I recommended. Stampeding Kodo is only good situationally, and is rather pricey for it's effect. Humility is useless a large amount of the time, especially when you're already running 2 Equalitys. If you still want a low drop in it's place, consider running Ironbeak Owl or another Acidic Swamp Ooze. Holy Light is usually considered not very good, as most pure healing spells tend to be, except as a  Priest. It has absolutely zero potential for card advantage.

Comment: @z- Imo, an excellent similar replacement for Stampeding Kodo would be another Avenging Wrath if you have one, as most minions with 2 or less attack will die to it. If you don't have one, other considerations are Noble Sacrifice and another Hammer of Wrath. Hammer of Wrath for obvious reasons, and Noble Sacrifice because it's a secret that's not bad to play even starting turn 1. Downside is your opponent will likely know exactly what the secret is and play around it. Although, that can sometimes be a good thing.

Comment: @z- In addition, I would consider adding your deck list to your original question still, in case some one has better ideas than I.

Comment: I'd also consider removing Humility; it's a dead card against most hunter creatures and you have Peacekeepers and spellbreakers for hyenas. Playing my hunter the most annoying thing is one or two minions on the board; don't play more than that if you can help it. High-efficiency minions are the way to go. Maybe some Ogres, Yetis, and a Defender of Argus would help. If you really like summoning bumpkins, I'd run Light's Justice.

Comment: @bombcar Why the light's justice if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Oops not a light's justice; that's the worst weapon in the game. I meant a sword of justice. Play it turn 3 against his turn 4 release, and you've nothing much on the board and start producing 2/2s the next turn.

Comment: I'd rather not post my deck up there so the question doesn't become too specific for just me.  Anyway, here's my updated deck: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Enj2N.png  I don't have 2 of most of those rares you mentioned.  I'm doing a bit better vs hunter zoo now, about 50/50 win rate, but I still take quite a bit of early game damage and I have a tough time keeping taunts down on the board late game via silences, kill commands, and hunter's marks.  I'm thinking of throwing in 2 sunfury protectors for 1 ooze 1 argent, what do you think?